# Including a tie into a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am doing a lab for my Python class in college. 
These are the instructions.

"*Write a Python program that will simulate a 
card
game.

In the game, two players are each given 
10 cards face down.  In each round, each player will turn over their top card.  The player with the 
highest card wins that round and all of the cards played during that round.

The cards won are 
added to the winner's
pile of cards.

While there is a tie
during a round
, each 
player will 
turn over their next card from their pile to 
determine the winner of the round.

If players run out of cards because of too many ties during a 
round, the player will be given new cards 
until a winner of the round is determined.

The game ends when a player runs out of cards. The winner of the game is the player who still 
has cards left at the end of the game.
A deck of cards can be represented by the numbers 1 
–
13, where 1 is a low Ace
, 11 is Jack, 12 is 
a Queen, and 13 is a King.  Face cards are represented by their numeric values 2 to 10.

Suit 
doesn't matter in this game.
Assume that you are writing the 
game 
for 2 players.  Use integer variables to keep up with the 
number of cards each player has in their hand.  Ra
ndomly generate the card values for each 
player's hand at the time the card is turned over in the round. 
(i.e. Do not store them ahead of 
time in a list.)

For this lab, don't worry about reusing the card values won in a round.  Instead 
just generate new 
random card values for each player for each round.
Make sure you output the values of each card played as well as the winner of each round.  If 
there is a tie, the output should relay that fact during the round.  At the end of the game, output 
the winner 
to the players.*"

**I have most of it figured out I think. 
However, I can't figure the tie out in the bottom while loop. 
It says to count the number of ties there are in a row and then give all of those cards to the eventual winner but I'm not sure how. 
When I run this code, it constantly tells me I have a tie and is an infinite loop. 
I'm just looking to be lead in the right direction.**

**Here is my code**

```
import random

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Game of War!")

    p1_deck = 10
    p2_deck = 10

    while(p1_deck or p2_deck >0):
        P1 = random.randrange(1,11)
        P2 = random.randrange(1,11)
        print("Player 1's card is", P1)
        print("Player 2's card is", P2)
        if(P1>P2):
            print("Player 1 wins the round!")
            p1_deck +=1  
            p2_deck -=1
            print("Player 1's deck now has", p1_deck,"cards.")
            print("Player 2's deck now has", p2_deck,"cards.")

        elif(P2>P1):
            print("Player 2 wins the round!")
            p2_deck +=1  
            p1_deck -=1
            print("Player 1's deck now has", p1_deck,"cards.")
            print("Player 2's deck now has", p2_deck,"cards.")

        else:
            while(P1==P2):
                print("It is a tie! To break the tie, another card must be turned over.")
                if(p1_deck==0 and p2_deck==0):
                    p1_deck +=1
                    p2_deck +=1
                    P1 = random.randrange(1,11)
                    P2 = random.randrange(1,11)
                    print("Player 1's card is", P1)
                    print("Player 2's card is", P2)
                    if(P1>P2):
                        print("Player 1 wins the round!")
                        p1_deck +=1  
                        p2_deck -=1
                    elif(P2>P1):
                        print("Player 2 wins the round!")
                        p2_deck +=1  
                        p1_deck -=1




main()
```

Comment: By the way `while(p1_deck or p2_deck >0):`  should read `while(p1_deck >0 or p2_deck >0):`. Your variant would coincidentally work here but is not what (I guess) you meant.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is happening because `P1` and `P2` start out equal, but your conditional statement resolves to `False`, so `P1` and `P2` never get the chance to change.  They're always the same.

Try adding in a `print` statement after your inner `while()` loop to see for yourself:

```
while(P1==P2):
    print(f"P1: {P1}, P2: {P2}")
    print(f"p1_deck: {p1_deck}, p2_deck: {p2_deck}")
    #...
```

Output:

```
P1: 2, P2: 2
p1_deck: 10, p2_deck: 10
It is a tie! To break the tie, another card must be turned over.
# infinite loop...
```

Think about how you might get `P1` and `P2` to update, even if your `_deck` values aren't zero.  Or, if you expect the `_deck` values to be zero, focus on why they're not.  That should be enough to get you some momentum here.  Good luck!

Comment: I took the tie out of my code to test it without it and it's never ending as well, and it allows the decks to go into the negative numbers. Why does it do this? I feel as if my first while loop isn't correct. It's supposed to end when a deck hits zero cards.

Comment: You wrote: "When I run this code, it constantly tells me I have a tie and is an infinite loop. I'm just looking to be lead in the right direction."  I hope my answer gave you a lead in the right direction for why it constantly tells you about the tie and the infinite loop.  I'm not sure what you're asking now, in your comment, but it sounds like a question that is additional to your question about the loop.  It's generally best to keep posts to one question at a time, or, alternately, clearly state the exact components of your question. Consider editing your initial post or opening a new one.

Comment: I figured everything out except my initial question. When their are two or more ties in a row, it is supposed to count those cards up and give the winner however many ties there was and the loser is supposed to lose that many cards. I can't figure out how to do that. That was the initial question.